# Easy way to update resources in iOS (without compilation)

Tags: ios, resources

I was wondering if there is any way to improve the workflow of programmers and designers in iOS without recorring to source control or code.

Currently I have a designer working with me that feels unconfortable with code and with source control. Then, I have to recompile everytime he wants to see a resource in the middle of the application.

I could use a webservice and only get the resources that changed everytime the application launches. However, I feel that this solution can be frustrating if he changes about 10 videos with 10-20 mega (new compression test, for instance).

In windows 8 I can create a folder with the resources in the library folder and he can access it and replace the resources. Then, the application can load all resources from that folder. But what can I do in iOS? There are no sd cards (or external hard drives) and I think I can't put resources together in a folder and load them in an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me I will make my app available in iTunes File Sharing by adding `UIFileSharingEnabled` to the Info.plist

Then I wrap my call to loading resources with a custom method, for example:

```
- (NSString *)pathForImage:(NSString *)imageName
{
    // Somewhere like this:
    // /var/mobile/Applications/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF/Documents/images/
    NSString *imagesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    imagesPath = [imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];

    NSString *path = [imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        return path;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *fileName = [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSString *fileExt = [imageName pathExtension];
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileExt];
    }
}
```

And change my image loading code from

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
```

to

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self pathForImage:@"foo.png"]];
```

Next time when the designer want to update a resource, he/she can open iTunes and drag-n-drop the new file into your app.
[image: iTunes File Sharing]
For more information about iTunes File Sharing, take a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20).

**UPDATE**: If your app don't utilize iTunes File Sharing for end users, remember to turn it off by removing `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the Info.plist! Otherwise Apple might reject your app because you enabled a feature that isn't used, and this may confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

in the simulator it works, on the device, exchange a resource breaks the code signature... of course you could also change the app so images are loaded from the apps library folder... he wants to ssh into the iphone or so?

*I* would install him xcode and the simulator (Actually I got our designers to use xcode and they could build the app!)

Comment: I believe that simulator doesn't provide an accurate color definition. Also, as I said I wanted to avoid making him use XCode. I wanted some solution that looks like the one I was thinking for windows 8 (a folder that the designer can replace the resources).

Comment: I provided a reason why it isnt so simple. and I asked about ssh (which works with jailbrak only AFAIK) .. I dont see it :(

Comment: Jailbrake isn't an option I believe. Probably I can find out how to do it with ssh but I doubt it will be easy for the designer to replace images.